# need to select the "correct" driver using powershell

Tags: powershell, properties, registry, driver

I have a problem.

I have this lovely piece of Powershell code.  It removes several old Wi-Fi drivers and then installs the correct one (Intel Wireless-AC 8265 20.0.2.3).  Seems to work well.

Then I **try** and change the adapter settings, using "Get-ItemProperty" look for a value, then when i find that value, I "Set-ItemProperty" and attempt to update the registry.

When I try to "Set-ItemProperty" to update the value, I get Requested Registry access is not allowed.

I appreciate you looking at my problem and hope that you can provide some direction that I can understand.

```
# set intel wireless adapter settings
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class -Recurse -ErrorAction silentlyContinue | 
Get-ItemProperty |
ForEach-Object {
if  ($_.RoamingPreferredBandType -ge 0)  {
    $path = $_.pspath

    # power management, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (auto); 0 = PSP CAM
    Set-ItemProperty $path -name "PowerIndex" -Value "0"

    # preferred band, 0 = no pref, 1 = 2.4GHz, 2 = 5.2GHz
    Set-ItemProperty $path -name "RoamingPreferredBandType" -Value "0"

    # roaming aggressiveness, 0 to 4 (highest); 3 = medium high
    Set-ItemProperty $path -name "RoamAggressiveness" -Value "3"

    # transmit power, 0, 25, 50, 75, 100
    Set-ItemProperty $path -name "IbssTxPower" -Value "100"

    # print path where settings applied
    write-output "applied adapter settings to:"
    write-output $_.pspath
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to give this post a read, https://serverfault.com/questions/884292/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-powershell, good luck